# Can I choose the fill based on the color?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following example data:

```r
d <- data.frame(x = 1:3, y = 1:3, category = letters[1:3], p = c(TRUE, TRUE, FALSE))
```

I'd like to plot this coloring by category.

```r
ggplot(d, aes(x, y, color = category) + geom_point(shape = "circle filled")
```

Then I'd like to make the fill:

- the same as the category if `p` is `TRUE`
- white otherwise

```r
ggplot(d, aes(x, y, color = category, fill = ???) + geom_point(shape = "circle filled")
```

Has anyone any suggestions?

Could I

- access the color scale results and then manipulate them?
- calculate color and fill manually, but still have the same legend labels?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `fill = after_scale(color)` to assign the fill to the same value as the color scale. Using `after_scale(ifelse(p, color, "white")` should give you the optional white fill value instead.

The only minor snag is that the usual NSE we get inside `aes` doesn't work inside `after_scale`, so we need to use `d$p` instead of just `p` for the first argument of `ifelse`

```r
ggplot(d, aes(x, y, color = category)) +
  geom_point(aes(fill = after_scale(ifelse(d$p, color, "white"))),
             shape = "circle filled", size = 10)
```

[image]

Comment: This works. Here is a variation which avoids the `d$p` trick: `ggplot(d, aes(x, y, color = category, fill = stage(p, after_scale = ifelse(fill == "white", fill, color)))) + geom_point(shape = "circle filled") + scale_fill_manual(values = c("TRUE" = "white", "FALSE" = "black"))`

Comment: @dash2 Indeed. Although this is more complex than just adding a `d$`, there may be cases where it is preferable to do it that way (e.g. if you pipe a filtered data frame in)